# How do I parse a text file in dictionary form and put it into a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, parsing

I want to take a text file that contains something of the form:

```
{('q0','a'):('q0','a','R'),
('q0','b'):('q0','a','R'),
('q1',' '):('q1',' ','L')}
```

and place it into a real dictionary.
I've been hacking away at this for hours and have gotten very far.
I think the solution is simple but I have found nothing useful on the internet. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your example looks like JSON. What forms do your text files normally take?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file contains valid Python code describing a dictionary, just use `eval`:

```
>>> value = "{('q0','a'):('q0','a','R'),('q0','b'):('q0','a','R'),('q1',' '):('q1',' ','L')}"
>>> value
"{('q0','a'):('q0','a','R'),('q0','b'):('q0','a','R'),('q1',' '):('q1',' ','L')}"
>>> d = eval(value)
>>> type(d)
<type 'dict'>
>>> d
{('q1', ' '): ('q1', ' ', 'L'), ('q0', 'a'): ('q0', 'a', 'R'), ('q0', 'b'): ('q0', 'a', 'R')}
```

However, I wouldn't recommend this method of passing information around (between Python programs, say). For that I would use something like pickle, or perhaps json serialization, depending on the exact needs.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> ast.literal_eval('''{('q0','a'):('q0','a','R'),
... ('q0','b'):('q0','a','R'),
... ('q1',' '):('q1',' ','L')}
... ''')
{('q1', ' '): ('q1', ' ', 'L'), ('q0', 'a'): ('q0', 'a', 'R'), ('q0', 'b'):
  ('q0', 'a', 'R')}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `exec` statement:

```
>>> d="""{('q0','a'):('q0','a','R'),
... ('q0','b'):('q0','a','R'),
... ('q1',' '):('q1',' ','L')}"""
>>> exec("myDict=%s" % d)
>>> myDict
{('q1', ' '): ('q1', ' ', 'L'), ('q0', 'a'): ('q0', 'a', 'R'), ('q0', 'b'): ('q0
', 'a', 'R')}
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to do what you want is by using eval statement. However, if the file gets tampered, it may cause security problems. I'd highly reccomend using [Pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) to store your dictionaries into a file.